# Leave workflow design

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am new to Workflows. Below is a sample application i am planning to develop using WF4 and ASP.NET

1. An employee will raise request for leave. This will be send to Manager
2. Manager will review it and approves or may ask for further clarification; then it will be redirected to employee.
3. HR will review and approves or may ask for further clarification; it will be again redirected to the employee

Below are few queries related to the App:

1. How can we go directly to a specific transition from ASP.NET in workflow

Scenario:

Manager approves..but HR denied. In this case employee will give some clarification and resubmits. In this case there is no need for Manager approval. So, we have to redirect directly to HR.

Question:

1. Is the requirement possible through WF4 using StateMachine in ASP.NET

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You may create two events "WaitingManagerApproval" and "WaitingHRApproval" to cater your scenario.